# create new data set by grouping SAS

Tags: sas

```
NAME  DATE
----  ---------- 
BOB   24/05/2013
BOB   12/06/2012
BOB   19/10/2011
BOB   05/02/2010
BOB   05/01/2009
CARL  15/05/2011
LOUI  15/01/2014
LOUI  15/05/2013
LOUI  15/05/2012

DATA newdata;
  SET mydata;
  count + 1;
  IF FIRST.name THEN count=1;
  BY name DESCENDING date;
run;
```

here i got count group wise 1,2,3 so on..I want the output of name(all obs of bob)  if count> 3. please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this shows the power of SQL - though some would say since this generates a NOTE in the log it isn't good practice.  Use the GROUP & HAVING clause in SQL to create a count of the names that you then limit to 3.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *
from have
group by name
having count(name)>3;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do that is to output the last row for each ID if it is > 3, then merge that dataset back to your master dataset, keeping only matches.  You could also use `PROC FREQ` to generate the dataset of counts and merge to that.

You can do it in a single datastep using a DoW loop, but that's more complicated, so I wouldn't recommend a new user do that.

Comment: Thanks.. it working with merge.. Can you give hint  for loop.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple different ways to do this using [SUBQUERIES](http://www.lexjansen.com/nesug/nesug98/dbas/p005.pdf) in PROC SQL

```
Data HAVE;
    Length NAME $50;
    Input Name $ Date: ddmmyy10.;
    Format date ddmmyy10.;
    datalines;
BOB  24/05/2013
BOB  12/06/2012
BOB  19/10/2011
BOB  05/02/2010
BOB  05/01/2009
CARL 15/05/2011
LOUI 15/01/2014
LOUI 15/05/2013
LOUI 15/05/2012
;
Run;
```

Using a multiple-value subquery in the Where statement

```
    Proc sql;
        Create table WANT1 as
        Select *
        From Have
        Where Name in (Select name from have b group by b.name having count(b.name)>3);
    Quit;
```

Using a subquery in the From clause

```
    Proc sql;
        Create table WANT2 as
        Select a.name, a.date
        From Have a Inner Join (select name, count(name) as Count from have b group by b.name having Count>3)
            On a.name=b.name
        ;
    Quit;
```